# Joomla 3 save form data to database with JTable

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, components, jquery-jtable

I have problem with saving data to database using JTable. I follow standard joomla documetation for creating component. I have database table `tests` with `id`, `title`, `description` and `created_by` columns. I was able to create form with title, description and using standard save function (not edited) save thouse values into database. But I want to insert user id to `created_by` column, but dont know how to do it.

Dont know if I can define `<input type="hidden">` in edit.php view tmpl, or shoud I somehow edit controller or table file?

Can't figure out how joomla parse form data to save them into database using JTable.

Comment: It will be hard to debug without sharing the part of your code with problem.

Comment: More likely i need help with understand how it works... But i will post my code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my edit.php tmpl for test view:

```
<?php
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_etesty&layout=edit&id='.(int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset class="adminform">
        <legend><?php echo JText::_( 'COM_ETESTY_TEST_DETAILS' ); ?></legend>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): ?>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="control-label"><?php echo $field->label; ?></div>
                        <div class="controls"><?php echo $field->input; ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div>
<?php


    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $user_id = $user->id;
    echo '<input type="text" name="jform[created_by]" value="' . $user_id . '" />';
    ?>




    <input type="hidden" name="task" value="test.edit" />
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is my model test.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla modelform library
jimport('joomla.application.component.modeladmin');

/**
 * Test Model
 */
class ETestyModelTest extends JModelAdmin
{
/**
 * Returns a reference to the a Table object, always creating it.
 *
 * @param   type    The table type to instantiate
 * @param   string  A prefix for the table class name. Optional.
 * @param   array   Configuration array for model. Optional.
 * @return  JTable  A database object
 * @since   1.6
 */
public function getTable($type = 'Test', $prefix = 'ETestyTable', $config = array()) 
{
    $table = JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
    return $table;
}
/**
 * Method to get the record form.
 *
 * @param   array   $data       Data for the form.
 * @param   boolean $loadData   True if the form is to load its own data (default case), false if not.
 * @return  mixed   A JForm object on success, false on failure
 * @since   1.6
 */
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) 
{
    // Get the form.
    $form = $this->loadForm('com_etesty.test', 'test', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
    if (empty($form)) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return $form;
}
/**
 * Method to get the data that should be injected in the form.
 *
 * @return  mixed   The data for the form.
 * @since   1.6
 */
protected function loadFormData() 
{
    // Check the session for previously entered form data.
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_etesty.edit.test.data', array());
    if (empty($data)) 
    {
        $data = $this->getItem();
    }
    return $data;
}
}
```

And here is table in component/tables/test.php

```
<?php
// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import Joomla table library
jimport('joomla.database.table');

/**
 * Test Table class
 */
class ETestyTableTest extends JTable
{
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param object Database connector object
 */
function __construct(&$db) 
{
    parent::__construct('#__etesty_test', 'id', $db);
}
}
```

And my form in component/models/forms/test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
<fieldset>
    <field
        name="id"
        type="hidden"
    />
    <field
        name="nazev"
        type="textarea"
        label="COM_ETESTY_TEST_NAZEV_LABEL"
        description="COM_ETESTY_TEST_NAZEV_DESC"
        class="text_area"
        default=""
    />
    <field
        name="popis"
        type="text"
        label="COM_ETESTY_TEST_POPIS_LABEL"
        description="COM_ETESTY_TEST_POPIS_DESC"
        size="255"
        class="inputbox"
        default=""
    />
    <field
        name="tema"
        type="modal_temata"
        label="COM_ETESTY_TEMA_LABEL"
        description="COM_ETESTY_TEMA_DESC"
    />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Its in czech language nazev = title, popis = description. And i need to get in there user id to save it into my database where i created column created_by.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller file add these codes. Do not add created_by in your form.

```html
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$data['created_by'] = $user->id;

$model = $this->getModel('yourmodel');

$model->store($data);
```